# Equal width elements in Jetpack Compose Row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

What is the easiest way to make the width the same for all the children of a `Row` in Jetpack Compose? For example, if there are 4 `Box` elements within a `Row`, I want each `Box` to have 1/4 the width (minus the padding) of the entire row.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use *modifier*. Row which contains max width and add weight to the box like

```
Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(1f)
```

For example,

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(5.dp)
) {
    for (i in 0..3) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
                .background(Color.Blue)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Use `spacedBy` attribute on Row and `weight` modifier on children. Checkout the below example:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun EquiRow() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        repeat(4) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .height(96.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

use the **weight** modifier.. `Modifier.weight(1)` on all the elements

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Modifier.weight(1f)` on the row's children.

A good example is these 3 Texts with different lengths.

```
 Row(Modifier.padding(4.dp)) {
    
            Text(
                text = "boy",
                modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .border(width = 1.dp, Color.Blue, shape = RectangleShape)
                        .padding(4.dp)
    
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = "girls",
                modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .border(width = 1.dp, Color.Blue, shape = RectangleShape)
                        .padding(4.dp)
    
            )
    
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = "countries",
                modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                        .border(width = 1.dp, Color.Blue, shape = RectangleShape)
                        .padding(4.dp)
    
            )
...}
```

We simply apply `Modifier.weight (1F)` to make the width the same despite the different number of characters.